# How to implement a 48x48 multiplier using DSP48E slices in Verilog HDL?

Tags: multiplier, virtex-series-fpga

Is it possible to create a 24x16 multiplier using DSP48E slice from a 25x18 dedicated multiplier in Virtex-7? Please post a sample code...
Are any advanced multipliers of these available?

Comment: Your question body does not match your question title. Your question body also doesn't make sense.

Comment: Edit your question properly in consistent with the title ...

Comment: The vhdl tag is for VHDL (Very high scale integrated circuit Hardware Description Language) not Verilog.

Comment: Vasudeva - Why did you change the text to ask about creating a 24x16 multiplier instead of a 48x48 multiplier? If it's a new problem you are having, it is better to [ask a new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) so that the answer already below matches the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Reinstate Monica - Sorry for that. We indeed trying to make a 48x48 multiplier using 24x16 multipliers that can be created from a DSP48E slices that have a 25x18 multiplier.

Comment: You are still asking about dogs with title cats.

Answer (score 1):

[DSP48E1](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug479_7Series_DSP48E1.pdf) slice in 7-series Xilinx FPGAs contains a 25x18 multiplier. You can make use of those DSP slices in your FPGA to implement bigger multipliers.

Following simple behavioral code inferred me a 48x48 multiplier using DSP slices on Virtex-7, when synthesised in Vivado.  Vivado synthesiser is smart enough to map the logic automatically to DSP slices, which you can see in the synthesis report.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Multiplier_VHDL is
   port
   (
      x, y       : in std_logic_vector(47 downto 0);
      clk, rst   : in std_logic;
      result     : out std_logic_vector(95 downto 0)
   );
end entity Multiplier_VHDL;

architecture Behavioral of Multiplier_VHDL is
begin
   process(clk)
   begin
      if rst = '0' then
         result <= (others => '0');
      elsif rising_edge(clk) then
         result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(x) * unsigned(y));
      end if;
   end process;
end architecture Behavioral;
```

[image]

P.S I am a VHDL guy. You can try the same in Verilog.

Comment: In Verilog we do the same. Just multiply two 48 bit vectors (signed or unsigned) and Xilinx will cascade the multipliers for you.

Comment: yea, but without the headache of type conversions ;)

Comment: @MituRaj if X, Y, and result were defined as unsigned to begin with on the ports, there would be no type conversions.  The type conversions were just a result of how the entity was defined in this case, not anything inherent to VHDL (other than that VHDL is strongly typed).

Comment: That's right. But std logic vector is still the standard interface used by most IPs. So I personally prefer that on top level ports for ease of portability.